# Robot Framework Test Case Generation from Within a Test Case?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, robotframework, testcase

I am using Robot Framework to automate onboard unit testing of a Linux based device.

The device has a directory /data/tests that contains a series of subdirectories, each subdirectory is a test module with 'run.sh' to be executed to run the unit test.  For example :

/data/tests/module1/run.sh

/data/tests/module2/run.sh

I wrote a function that collects the subdirectory names in an array, and this is the list of test modules to be executed.  The number of modules can vary daily.

```
@{modules}=     SSHLibrary.List Directories in Directory       /data/tests
```

Then another function (Module Test) that basically runs a FOR loop on the element list and executes the run.sh in each subdirectory, collects log data, and logs it to the log.html file.

The issue I am experiencing is that when the log.html file is created, there is one test case titled Module Test, and under the FOR loop, a 'var' entry for each element (test module).  Under each 'var' entry are the results of the module execution.

Is it possible from within the FOR loop, to create a test case for each element and log results against it?  Right now, if one of the modules / elements fails, I do not get accurate results, I still get a pass for the Module Test test case.  I would like to log test cases Module 1, Module 2, ... , Module N, with logs and pass fail for each one.  Given that the number of modules can vary from execution to execution, I cannot create static test cases, I need to be able to dynamically create the test cases once the number of modules has been determined for the test run.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Dan.

Comment: you want to dynamically create code (modules) during runtime, pre or post compilation? Include some sample code of function Module Test please. Why can't you use [data driven tests for the framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot_Framework)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a simple script that dynamically create the robot test file by reading the `/data/test/module*`, then create one test case for each of the modules. In each test case, simply run the operating system command and check the return code (the `run.sh`). 
This way, you get one single test suite, with many test cases, each representing a module.

Answer (score 0):

Consider writing a bash script that would run robot test for each module, and then merge reports to one report with rebot script. Use a --name parameter in pybot script to differentiate tests in report.